# Delete children in Javascript DOM, console result different from in-page result

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to dynamically delete all (dynamically added) children from a simple web page, and I found that when I click my button to run the JavaScript code in the web page, the resulting deletion is different than if I run the same code in the browser console.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onclick="addText()">
        <h1 id="my_text">Click on the page.</h1>
        <button onclick="deleteText()">Click here to remove text node</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addText() {
    newText = document.createTextNode("This is dynamically added text");
    newText.id = "dynamicText";

    var textPart = document.getElementById("my_text");
    textPart.appendChild(newText);
}

function deleteText() {
    var parent = document.getElementById("my_text");

    while (parent.childNodes[1]) {
        parent.removeChild(parent.childNodes[1]);
    }
}
```

In the browser, I click on the header to dynamically append text nodes to the header.  Then I wish to click the button to delete all the dynamically added text.  When I click the button in the browser, it deletes all of the dynamically added text except one newText element, resulting in this:

```
Click on the page.This is dynamically added text
```

But, when I execute the same code ( or even just call the function deleteText() ) in the browser console, it deletes all newText elements as desired, resulting in this:

```
Click on the page.
```

I'm wondering, why is the result different when the code is executed from the browser window versus in the browser console?  I'm using Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 m

Comment: This is not causing your issue, but as a side note, you are assigning the same ID to all of your new text nodes `newText.id = "dynamicText";` ... DOM ID values are required to be unique within the DOM tree. Having duplicate IDs can cause unexpected behavior in both Javascript and CSS. You may want to use a _class_ instead. You should also use `var` on _newText_: `var newText = document....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because when you click your "remove" button you are still clicking in the body tag, so the onclick in the `<body>` tag is still being triggered adding a text node again.